# Make sure image has loaded before do something with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a gallery on my app. There are plenty of thumbnails that `fadeOut` to make room for new thumbnails. I know I can preload it on another div, set a timeout and then change the thumbnail src to the preloaded one. But, it does not guarantee that the image will be loaded, right?
Now, im doing like this:

```
var img = $('<img />');
img.attr('src','path/to/img');

img.on('load',function(){
    // change the src
    // fadeOut
    // fadeIn
});
```

It appears to be working, but I have some questions:

1. Will it work even when the requested URL responds with a 404?
2. I've set a **timeout** to run this every 3 seconds. Is it bad?
3. I don't know how JavaScript works in general, so, creating a new **img** element on each execution of this code can give me some trouble? I'm worried because I don't know if this will be stacked somewhere (this code can be running for hours).

Comment: Take a look at the [docs for the load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/), the `complete` callback receives some arguments that hold information about the request - you'll be able to detect a 404 or any other HTTP codes with these arguments.

Comment: @Lix Humm.. Actually, it seems that I was trying to use a deprecated function. [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). I changed my code to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use jQuery's .fail() functionality. E.g.:

   ```
   img.on('load', function() {
       // do your stuff here
   })
   .fail(function() {
       // whatever you want to do here
   });
   ```
2. It depends on the JS-engine. Older IE had leaks. But after the timeout is done, it's done. So I can see nothing bad here. Modern apps/webpages have so much scripts running that a little timeout does no harm.
3. I'd remove unused img-elements. Otherwise you might blow up the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All elements that I append to the html are being used. My question is about the element that I am creating on the function scope. How does its lifecycle works? Is it appended to the DOM?

Comment: I asume you are adding it to a container via .append()? Then yes, it becomes part of the DOM and will stay there until you delete it or the user cancels your app.

Comment: Actually I am using .html on a div

Comment: So you are replacing the content of that div.